# Intuitive understanding of the Boolean Hierarchy

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am trying to understand the Boolean Hierarchy. the formal definition of the Boolean Hierarchy is as follows:

- $BH_1 = NP$
- $BH_{2k}$ is the class of languages which are the intersection of a
  language in $BH_{2k-1}$ and a language in $coNP$.
- $BH_{2k+1}$ is the class of languages which are the intersection of a
  language in $BH_{2k}$ and a language in $NP$.
- $BH$ is the union of the $BH_i$

I am clear with the formal definition but not many sources explain it intuitively. Lets decipher it as follows:

- $BH_1 = NP_0$
- $BH_2 = NP_0\cap coNP_1$
- $BH_3 = (NP_0\cap coNP_1) \cup (NP_1)$

Thus if language is in $BH_3$ iff: Its first language (namely $NP_0$) is satisfiable, second language (namely $coNP_0$) is unsatisfiable, and third language (namely $NP_1$) is satisfiable.

Alternatively, can we define the complexity levels in $BH$ as follows:

$BH_i$: A language is in $BH_i$ iff it requires $i$ oracle calls to an $NP$-oracle to solve the problem in polynomial time. Thus, for any $BH_i$ there seems to be no algorithm that solves the problem in polynomial time with $j$ oracle calls, where $(j<i)$ to an $NP$-oracle ((in the worst case).

Is this alternate definition equivalent to the formal definition or there is some flaw in the understanding?

Comment: Every level of the Boolean hierarchy contains P.

Comment: The way I understand the first level is $NP$ thus it requires 1 call to $NP$ oracle to solve it in polynomial time and so on. Can we say the classes below ($P$ as you said) are at the 0th level and will require 0 calls to this oracle to solve the problem in polynomial time? Its seems consistent.

Comment: NP contains P. A problem in NP doesn't "require" a single oracle call. It's exactly the opposite: it can be *solved* using a single oracle call (and in a particular way).

Comment: When I said it requires an oracle call I meant the same i.e. $BH_i$ can be solved  in polynomial time with 'i' oracle calls to an NP oracle. am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: The word *require* usually has a different connotation in English.

Comment: I encourage you to check the references in the paper mentioned in my answer.

Comment: ok. Can I update it as follows: "$BH_i$ can be solved in polynomial time if it can make $i$ oracle calls to an NP-oracle?" If not i would be thankful if you could update it with a more correct version. I hope though the essence of the definition I wrote is correct?

Comment: thank you. I will..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boolean hierarchy is *cumulative*: $\mathrm{BH}_n \subseteq \mathsf{BH}_{n+1}$. In particular, all levels of the Boolean hierarchy contain $\mathrm{P}$.

The introduction to Pitassi, Shirley and Watson's [Nondeterministic and Randomized Boolean Hierarchies in
Communication Complexity](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/043/) contains some equivalent definitions of the Boolean hierarchy, and relevant pointers to the literature. The simplest definition that they give is: $\mathrm{BH}_n$ is the set of decision problems computable by making $n$ many $\mathrm{NP}$ oracle calls, and outputting the parity of the result.

Comment: thank you. I understood why the word 'required' was incorrect. Hats off and a ton of thanks for this insight. It should have been "at most i queries' or 'i queries in the worst case'. thanks again!

Comment: I too am trying to develop a better intuition for the Boolean hierarchy. One problem that I have today is I can't see whether DP (i.e., all languages of the form L ⧵ L' for L,L' languages in NP) is closed under reductions, e.g., polynomial-time many-one reductions. I don't see this point mentioned in some of the papers I've looked at, which is surprising since it seems a very natural question. More frustrating is that I can't find an easy proof (or disproof) on my own.

Comment: You can always ask a new question on this point.